# CakePHP & MySQL - Using find('all') with GROUP for one field and MAX for another field

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns (`thread_id`, `message_id`, `message`). Along the lines of the solution found under the "Example using GROUP BY" in this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php), I want my query to GROUP BY `thread_id`, but return the line of of the highest `message_id` (instead of default lowest) for each `thread_id`. I then want a nicely formatted array with lines/items just like you get for less complex find operations in CakePHP along the lines of `$array[index]['Model']['field']`. Using the following CakePHP syntax:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('MAX(Model.message_id) as message_id', 'Model.thread_id', 'Model.message'),
   'group => 'Model.thread_id'
));
```

Now, unfortunately I am not getting that nicely formatted array. Instead I get an array which looks something like:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message_id] => wanted/correct_message_id ) [Model] => Array ( [message] => Message from lowest/unwanted message_id line. [thread_id] => Key from lowest/unwanted message_id line))

Why does the `message_id` not get hooked onto the `[Model]` part of the array and why does CakePHP fetch the lowest `message_id` line and put the `message` and `thread_id` into the `[Model]` part of the array without the `message_id` column?

I want all thre columns in the `[Model]` part of the array and I want that line to be the highest `message_id` for that `thread_id` per my initial description. Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: To get it into the model key, set it up as a `virtualField`

Comment: Ok. Will the desired line (highest) then be fetched into the model key?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual fields are really useful for this kind of thing.

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'max_message_id' => 'MAX(MyModel.message_id)'
    );

}
```

You can now use max_message_id as if it were a normal field in your table, so you can add it to your find operations.

Comment: Ok interesting. Will the SQL query be different to my example above? In this case, does the virtual field make the default query always finding the highest message_id line instead of lowest (like I wanted)?

Comment: All `$virtualFields` does is allow you to write custom SQL like you've done, but have the result pulled into the associative array as though it's a real table field. Otherwise, it should behave in exactly the same way. You can also set the value of your model's `$virtualFields` before calling `find()` if you don't always want to be using it.

Comment: @user1469742 The virtual field will not affect your normal queries, so if you want to find just the normal message_id you find `message_id`, but if you want to find the maximum message ID, you use `max_message_id`.